# How to access Customer table's data in nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, nopcommerce

I want to show Customer table's data of `nopcommerce` in admin page.
i did write a `plugin` for that and receive data in controller but in view i have a problem and show me `error happened` message.
here is my `controller` code:

```
  public class UserDetailsController : BasePluginController
{
    private ICustomerService _UserDetail;
    public UserDetailsController(ICustomerService UserDetail)
    {
        _UserDetail = UserDetail;
    }

    public ActionResult Manage()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetUsers(DataSourceRequest userDetail)
    {
        var details = _UserDetail.GetAllCustomers();
        var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
         {
             Data = details,
             Total = details.Count
         };
        return Json(gridModel);
    }
}
```

And this is my `view` code:

```
   @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}


<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#user-details").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("GetUsers", "UserDetails"))",
                                    type: "POST",
                                    dataType: "json",

                                },
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data: "Data",
                                total: "Total",
                                errors: "Errors",
                                model: {
                                    id: "Id",
                                }
                            },
                            requestEnd: function(e) {
                                if (e.type == "update") {
                                    this.read();
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                                // Cancel the changes
                                this.cancelChanges();
                            },
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                            serverSorting: true
                        },
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            numeric: false,
                            previousNext: false,
                            info:false
                        },
                        editable: {
                            confirmation: true,
                            mode: "inline"
                        },
                        scrollable: false,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field: "Email",
                                title: "User Name",
                                width: 200
                            }, 

                            {
                                command: [
                                    {
                                        name: "edit",
                                        text: "@T("Admin.Common.Edit")"
                                    }, {
                                        name: "destroy",
                                        text: "@T("Admin.Common.Delete")"
                                    }
                                ],
                                width: 200
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                });
</script>




<div id="user-details"></div>
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `GetUsers` method on this way:

```
 var details = _UserDetail.GetAllCustomers();

      var gridModel = new DataSourceResult
      {
           Data=details.Select(x=>
           {
             return new UserDetail()
             {
                Email= x.Email
             };
          }),

       Total = details.Count(),
     };

   return Json(gridModel);
```

Comment: what is dataList?!I had not any dataList.did you mean details?and another problem is,how you return new UserDetail?i cant do it and i think this code has some problem.

Comment: And this is a sample code, which gives you a hint that you could do like this way.

Comment: unfortunately no.actually i think i have not problem in controller.i get the records server side,i think my problem is in view and i did some mistakes in binding to the kendo grid but i do not know where.

Comment: You have commented on your last question *i receive empty rows without data* now you told that you get the record from server side. Please check console error.

Comment: maybe i confusing you and sorry about that.see, here is what i receive in view :  https://s14.postimg.org/ivpbmnlld/nopcommerce.jpg

Comment: See the plugin `Nop.Plugin.Feed.Froogle` > `FeedFroogleController` > `GoogleProductList`, basically you have to select particular column value which you want to display on grid. this `Data=details` will not work.